# Remove numbers in the middle of a string

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to remove excess decimals from a string using find/replace with regex.

For example :

```
<xml_taga>145.3345542123</xml_taga>
<xml_tagb>125.1245471</xml_tagb>
<xml_tagc>42.12</xml_tagc>
```

Should look like this:

```
<xml_taga>145.33</xml_taga>
<xml_tagb>125.12</xml_tagb>
<xml_tagc>42.12</xml_tagc>
```

The furthest I have gotten is with this expression

```
(\.\d{3,12})
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\d\.\d\d)\d+`     OR `\d\.\d\d\K\d+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=        : start lookbehind, make sure we have 
  \d\.\d\d  : a digit, a dot and 2 digits
)           : end lookbehind
\d+         : 1 or more digits
```

other alternative:

```
\d\.\d\d    : a digit, a dot and 2 digits
\K          : forget what we have seen until this point
\d+         : 1 or more digits
```

- *Check regular expression*

**Result for given example:**

```
<xml_taga>145.33</xml_taga>
<xml_tagb>125.12</xml_tagb>
<xml_tagc>42.12</xml_tagc>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to remove excess decimals from a string using find/replace with regex.

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `(\d+\.\d\d).*<`.
- Set "Replace with" to `\1<`
- Enable "Regular expression" and "matches newline"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

Before:

```
<xml_taga>145.3345542123</xml_taga>
<xml_tagb>125.1245471</xml_tagb>
<xml_tagc>42.12</xml_tagc>
```

After:

```
<xml_taga>145.33</xml_taga>
<xml_tagb>125.12</xml_tagb>
<xml_tagc>42.12</xml_tagc>
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: `.*` is greedy and may cause some problems when two tags in a line.

Comment: My edit has been rejected, I don't know why, You have dupplicated the original in "after" part instead of the result.